# VB.NET TcpListener FORM NOT SHOWING

Tags: vb.net, tcplistener

i'm using the above code to run a form with a tcplistener.

when the tcplistener recevie data from the client i need to write  the data in in label1.text

i have tryed to use Shown instead of Load the form is showed but it the label text doesn't change.

How can i resolve this? any help will be appreciated.

thank you

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

TcpServer()

End Sub

```
Shared Sub TcpServer()

    Dim server As TcpListener
    server = Nothing
    Try

        Dim port As Int32 = 4000
        Dim localAddr As IPAddress = IPAddress.IPv6Any 'IPAddress.Parse("192.168.61.9") 'IPAddress.Any 
        server = New TcpListener(localAddr, port)
        server.Start()

        Dim bytes(1024) As Byte
        Dim data As String = Nothing

        While True
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ")

            Dim client As TcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient()
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!")

            data = Nothing

            Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

            Dim i As Int32

            ' Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
            i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            While (i <> 0)
                ' Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i)
                Form1.Label1.Text = data

                ' Process the data sent by the client.
                'data = data.ToUpper()
                data = "aaa"
                Dim msg As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)

                ' Send back a response.
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length)
                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}" + data)

                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

            End While

            ' Shutdown and end connection
            client.Close()
            Form1.Refresh()
        End While
    Catch e As SocketException
        MsgBox("SocketException: {0}", e.ToString)
    Finally
        server.Stop()
    End Try

    Console.WriteLine(ControlChars.Cr + "Hit enter to continue....")
    Console.Read()
End Sub 'Main
```

Comment: [TcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync). Or [the version that uses an async Callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient). You cannot block the UI Thread with a `while` loop. A WinForms app is not a Console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run TcpServer() on a new thread, or make use of BackGroundWorker Control which is part of winForms controls.